# Modify a method on the fly in Ruby

Tags: ruby, active-record

I have about a hundred Rake tasks that are creating Rails models for me from a legacy datafile. Each task shares some setup and teardown code; all that sets them apart is the code in the middle. For example:

```
task countries: setup do
  rows = rows_from_file("system/countries", 2)
  bar = RakeProgressbar.new(rows.length)
  info "» Importing countries"
  rows.each do |row|
    Country.new(
      alpha2: row[0],
      name: row[1]
    ).save!
    bar.inc
  end
  bar.finished
end

task telephone_number_types: setup do
  rows = rows_from_file("system/telephone_number_types", 1)
  bar = RakeProgressbar.new(rows.length)
  info "» Importing telephone number types"
  rows.each do |row|
    TelephoneNumberType.new(
      name: row[0]
    ).save!
    bar.inc
  end
  bar.finished
end

task occupations: setup do
  rows = rows_from_file("system/occupations", 3)
  bar = RakeProgressbar.new(rows.length)
  info "» Importing occupations"
  rows.each do |row|
    Occupation.new(
      id: row[1],
      name: row[2]
    ).save!
    bar.inc
  end
  bar.finished
end
```

How could I extract the progress bar stuff so I don’t keep repeating it? I had thought of writing some generic method that takes the array of `rows` and some code block (which would contain the Model.new(attrs).save! code) and wraps that stuff with the progress bar stuff, but I can’t quite make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say you're on the right track with you idea to extract a method.

While I can't fully replicate your code and its context, I think something like this should work:

```
task countries: setup do |task_name|
  rows = rows_from_file("system/#{task_name.to_s}", 2)
  process_rows(task_name, rows) do |row|
    { alpha2: row[0], name: row[1] }
  end
end

# ...

def import_rows(task_name, rows, &block)
  klass = task_name.to_s.classify
  bar = RakeProgressbar.new(rows.length)
  info "» Importing #{task_name.to_s.humanize}"
  rows.each do |row|
    attrs = block.call(row)
    klass.new(attrs).save!
    bar.inc
  end
  bar.finished
end
```

But it's going *pretty* far in its assumptions - it's basing *a lot* off of the task name alone.

A somewhat less fragile approach might be this where the correct class is explicitly passed to the helper method and the file name isn't guessed from the task name

```
task countries: setup do
  rows = rows_from_file("system/countries", 2)
  process_rows(Country, rows) do |row|
    { alpha2: row[0], name: row[1] }
  end
end

# ...

def import_rows(klass, rows, &block)
  bar = RakeProgressbar.new(rows.length)
  info "» Importing #{klass.to_s.pluralize.humanize}"
  rows.each do |row|
    attrs = block.call(row)
    klass.new(attrs).save!
    bar.inc
  end
  bar.finished
end
```

Comment: That’s exactly the kind of thing I was shooting for. Thanks so much!